# How do I do a `git checkout` in visual studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, git-checkout

I'd like to go back and look at a commit of the code I previously published. From the command line, it would be `git checkout [commit id]`, but I'd like to do it though Visual Studio (2019) so I don't have to open the command prompt and find/copy the commit id. I don't want to make any permanent changes to the code, I just want to be able to browse/debug the old code.

This seems like it should be a feature in Visual Studio - from the history window, I can see options for `Revert`, `Reset`, `Cherry-Pick`, but I don't think any of those are re-named version of `checkout`. I tried searching for "visual studio 2019 how do I checkout a previous commit git" (and various wordings), but I can't find the answer.

The solution I've used so far was to make a new branch from the commit I want to look at, then delete the branch when done, but it seems like there must be a better way...

Here is the right-click menu:
[image: Commit History Right-Click Menu]

Comment: Can't you right click on a commit in the history panel, and checkout?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - No, I don't see a "checkout" option. I expected there to be one, but I don't have one. I'll add a screenshot, but my options are basically "Revert", "Reset", and "Cherry-Pick". Maybe one of those is a renamed version of "Checkout", but I don't think so.

Comment: Hm. I would just create a new branch from one of those commits, then.

Comment: I wonder if there's an extension for this. I haven't found any yet.

Comment: If you're able to use VS 2022, it has the option you're looking for "Checkout (--detach)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is not any way to do this in VS. You must do it in a command line. There is a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/i-want-to-be-able-to-git-checkout-an-old-commit-fr/648233) in VS community for adding this feature. You can log in and vote for that. Maybe that helps and you may see it in the next version of VS.

Comment: I've just upvoted the ticket. "I'm just doing my part."